Проблема с загрузкой видео с youtube
у меня есть вот такая программа:
from pytubefix import YouTube




url = r"https://youtube.com/shorts/GjXpmX4rVKQ?si=jFjDvagUa_Qxhykm"

yt = YouTube(url)
video = yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
print("download start")
try:
    video.download()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

и когда я её запускаю в консоль выводится ошибка: urlopen error [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера> как мне её исправить? timeOut не помог

Я боюсь, не у вас одного проблемы с youtube сейчас...

А если включить VPN работает?

У меня работает. Я не из РФ и у меня в моём селе 500-мегабитный Интернет. Качает мгновенно. Есть только один нюанс. Если в каталоге с программой этот закачиваемый файл уже есть, не выдаётся предупреждения или предложения перезаписать - просто не качает и всё. yt.streams.get_highest_resolution() тоже работает.

я включал goodbye DPI, но не помогало

@rifledPencil во-первых GoodbyeDPI это не VPN, а во-вторых повключайте по-другому https://habr.com/ru/articles/842996/
